# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'employee.urls'

Tags: django

While I'm trying to add a urls configuration in my urls.py file, I'm getting an error like **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'employee.urls'** and **OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''**

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('employee/',include("employee.urls"))
```

]

[directory and file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GyVF.png)

Comment: According to your file paths, you only have a `urls_employee` module in your `employee` app. No `urls` to be seen there.

Comment: have you add "employee" in installed_apps in settings.py?

Comment: yeah i have done tht already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a convention to name all your url config files `urls.py` not `url_<appname>` unless you have a very special use-case.

But in either case, you must import the url file after your **filename**. So if you want to keep the filename *as is*, try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('employee/',include("employee.urls_employee"))
```

Comment: yeah i got the solution. Thanks